# Filling in fields based on spinner selection (firestore)

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, spinner

I am new to programming and I need help
I learned how to add data from collections to the spinner, but I can't find information how to fill it in anywhere, for example, a TextView field based on the choice of the spinner's position.
Firestore:
[Firestore][1]

```
public class UserActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView tvName, tvCourse, tvGender, tvDescription;
    private ImageButton AddBtn, logoutBtn;
    private Spinner spListStudent;
    private Button btnNextActivity, btnThreeActivity ;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private DatabaseReference ref1;
    private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
    private int positionOfSelectedDataFromSpinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);

        tvName = findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        tvCourse = findViewById(R.id.tvCourse);
        tvGender = findViewById(R.id.tvGender);
        AddBtn = findViewById(R.id.AddBtn);
        logoutBtn = findViewById(R.id.logoutBtn);
        spListStudent = findViewById(R.id.spListStudent);
        btnNextActivity = findViewById(R.id.btnNextActivity);
        btnThreeActivity = findViewById(R.id.btnThreeActivity);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Please wait...");
        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        ref1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

        logoutBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                firebaseAuth.signOut();
                checkUser();
            }
        });

        AddBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(UserActivity.this, AddCollectionFirestore.class));
            }
        });
        addStudentToSpinner();
    }

    private void checkUser() {
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user==null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(UserActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
            finish();
        } else {
        }
    }

    private void addStudentToSpinner () {

        CollectionReference subjectsRef = firebaseFirestore.collection("accColl").document("usersCollection")
                .collection(firebaseAuth.getUid()).document("coll3").collection("students");
        List<String> subjects = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, subjects);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spListStudent.setAdapter(adapter);
        subjectsRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        String subject = document.getString("nameStudent");
                        subjects.add(subject);
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                spListStudent.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        String item = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item Selected "+position +
                                " " + item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        // Variant1
                        
                        subjectsRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot qS1 : task.getResult()) {
                                        String stDescr = qS1.getData().get("descriptionStudent").toString();
                                        tvCourse.setText(stDescr);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        // Variant2
                        
                        Query q2 = subjectsRef.orderBy("nameStudent");
                                
                        q2.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot sn1 : task.getResult()) {
                                        String stName = sn1.getData().get("nameStudent").toString();
                                        
                                        tvName.setText(stName);
                                    }
                                } else {
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Please help
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPjum.png

Comment: Your question is a little unclear to me. As far as I can see you're trying to access `item=parent.getSelectedItem().toString` but maybe you just forgot to set it to the required `TextView` using `setText`.

Comment: Also I don't understand why you are using the `CollectionReference` i.e. calling data from Firebase again and again because you can just fetch it once and then just get the selected item as described in the above comment

Comment: There is a collection of students ("students"), their names ("nameStudent") I added to the spinner. Now I need to display student description ("descriptionStudent") in the TextView (tvCourse) based on the student selected in the spinner.

Comment: Since all the collection parameters from your posted code are sameYou are still calling the same collection thrice in the code, you can call the data from the Firebase Collection just once, add it to a list and then perform the suitable manipulations

Comment: Also you are using `setOnItemSelectedListener` twice so only the latest one will take effect. I don't understand the reason for this too

Comment: "Also you are using setOnItemSelectedListener twice so only the latest one will take effect." Thanks for the comment, already fixed

Comment: Now what are you doing with the `item=parent.getSelectedItem().toString` line? You haven't used that selected item anywhere

Comment: Only in Toast, nowhere else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I found a solution to my question. Now, when you change the position of the spinner, the data in the textView changes

```
public class UserActivity5 extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView tvName, tvCourse, tvGender, tvDescription;
private Spinner spListStudent;

private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private DatabaseReference ref1;
private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
private DocumentReference dR1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user5);

    tvName = findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    tvCourse = findViewById(R.id.tvCourse);
    tvGender = findViewById(R.id.tvGender);
    tvDescription = findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
    spListStudent = findViewById(R.id.spListStudent);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Please wait...");
    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    dR1 = firebaseFirestore
            .collection("accColl")
            .document("usersCollection")
            .collection(firebaseAuth.getUid())
            .document("coll3");
    ref1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

    addStudentToSpinner();
}

private void addStudentToSpinner () {

    CollectionReference subjectsRef = firebaseFirestore
            .collection("accColl")
            .document("usersCollection")
            .collection(firebaseAuth.getUid())
            .document("coll3")
            .collection("students");

    List<String> subjects = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, subjects);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spListStudent.setAdapter(adapter);

    subjectsRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {

            for (DocumentSnapshot document : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments()) {
                String subject = document.getString("nameStudent");
                subjects.add(subject);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            spListStudent.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String item = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    subjectsRef
                            .whereEqualTo("nameStudent", item)
                            .get()
                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                            String stName = document.getData().get("nameStudent").toString();
                                            String stDescr = document.getData().get("descriptionStudent").toString();
                                            String stCourse = document.getData().get("courseStudent").toString();
                                            String stPhil = document.getData().get("philosophy").toString();
                                            tvName.setText(stName);
                                            tvGender.setText(stDescr);
                                            tvCourse.setText(stCourse);
                                            double philosophyParse = Double.parseDouble(stPhil);
                                            NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("##.#####");
                                            String phi = String.format(nf.format(philosophyParse));
                                            tvDescription.setText(phi);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else {
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                }
                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

}